# Where are Eclipse templates for Android activity classes kept?

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile

When you create a new Android Activity from Eclipse, it comes with some default code put in, including the onCreate and onStart methods. Where can I edit this template to add new methods that I want to be created by default when new Android activities are created?

Comment: I don't know if this is correct or not, so I won't post it as an answer, but there is a template.xml under android_home/tools/templates/activities/BlankActivity. Perhaps editing this will change the default new activities.

Comment: @monkybonk05 You got it, that's where it was (I had to go further into the src/ folder to find the template. ) Post as answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the template files located in android_home/tools/templates/activities/BlankActivity

Answer (score 0):

If you right click anywhere in your extended class, go to Sources-->Override/Implement Methods 
you can find all the methods that you can Override/Implement. Select all the ones you need and click ok

Comment: I'd rather if there was a template I can edit so I won't have to do this each time I make an activity